# How big is the performance difference between Oracle and PostgreSQL?

Tags: performance, oracle, postgresql

I'm wondering about how to scale a database. Currently it uses PostgreSQL. Would switching to Oracle be worthwhile inspite of the coding pain and expense? Or is PostgreSQL + more boxes a better/cheaper approach?

Comment: I imagine postgres would be cheaper.

Comment: How long is a piece of string? There are so many factors involved, that there is no one right answer here.

Comment: Doesn't that depend very much on the workload and queries? Perhaps it is even possible to optimize your current queries. I believe PostgreSQL has quite a good query analyzer. More boxes might be cheaper but the complexity of sharding is also not to be underestimated.

Comment: I don't like Oracle. For now all it's been to me was a pain in the neck. No other RDBMS (PostgreSQL, MSSQL, MySQL, FirebirdSQL) has given me so much headache. From client connectivity to stored procedures returning cursors.

Comment: Oh, and do consider just upping the amount of RAM / query cache, or possibly move from harddisk to flash storage. If IO is the bottleneck that can also increase performance (at a price). It really is dependent on the workload.

Comment: Companies like NTT and Skype use a lot of PostgreSQL-boxes and save a lot of money. And it all depends on your specific situation.

Comment: This question can only be answered anecdotally because of Oracle not allowing benchmarks against other RDBMS to be published.

Answer (score 16):

IME there's not a lot between any of the major DBMS in terms of the performance that you can achieve by performance tuning. It's not just my experience [Open Source PostgreSQL Trails Oracle In Benchmark, But Not By Much](https://www.informationweek.com/open-source-postgresql-trails-oracle-in-benchmark-but-not-by-much-/d/d-id/1057195)

There is no substition for finding any performance problems and fixing them both in terms of client side and database optimisiation.

Comment: +1 for focusing on the existing problems rather than creating a whole bunch of interesting new ones.

Comment: After working full time with Oracle and Postgres and running similar loads, if there's a difference - it just doesn't feel like much difference.  +1 for not opening up a whole new mess.

Comment: Note that the benchmark results Richard linked to here were using PostgreSQL 8.2; version 8.3 had a very large performance gain compared to earlier versions, in pretty much every way.  Oracle may have improved some, too, but PostgreSQL is commonly 30 to 50% faster now than version 8.2 was.

Answer (score 5):

I think that what you're suggesting is logically equivalent to [Things You Should Never Do, Part I](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000069.html).  This type of conversion is effectively a rewrite, and converting from one database to another (or one language to another, etc) is a great way to kill a lot of time and money that could otherwise be spent on actually improving your product.  A better choice, as @Richard Harrison said above, would be to spend some time fixing whatever performance issues are driving you to consider moving to Oracle.  As Fred Brooks said many years ago, there is [No Silver Bullet](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~cah/G51ISS/Documents/NoSilverBullet.html).

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 5):

It wouldn't be an upgrade to go to Oracle.  Just a migration.  If you wish to upgrade Postgresql I strongly suggest you move to EnterpriseDB's Postgres Plus.  They have created a Oracle compatible version of Postgres that will run all of the existing code, any new oracle centric code.  Nearly all of the features anyone would buy oracle rdms for are in it.  It is really fast too.

If you are jealous of RAC, don't be.  RAC is very expensive to maintain and is not real efficient per new box added.  You can get the additional performance without the cost out of postgres.  Look into PGPOOL as a solution for horizontal growth without the cost.

Comment: PGPOOL does not do shared-storage clustering.  It's based on data replication.  RAC instances can share data storage.  When you have multiple terabytes of data, the replication needed to run PGPOOL can be extremely expensive in both performance and storage costs.

Answer (score -1):

I'll admit up front that I'm biased here, but I gotta tell you [PostgreSQL](http://postgresql.org) is an amazing product! I'll admit I don't have any direct experience with Oracle, but everything I've ever read puts PostgreSQL within such a close range that even if it is a bit slower there is no question on my mind that spending any amount you could spend on licensing for Oracle instead on hardware or additional development time (to improve performance) should still leave you ahead in both dollars and performance.

Of course I do stipulate as others above have said that this is a question that really is too subjective unless we are going to talk about a particular situation or installed environment.